# What does "became hot network question" mean?

Tags: support, questions

While checking my [question's history](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/264658/timeline) (for the first time as I remember), I clicked the tiny clock like symbol beside the vote signs on my question and saw

> 16 hours ago  history **became hot network question**

I don't understand what that means. Then I went around checking some other questions, most of them had the same thing in their history. Like [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/264480/timeline), [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/261842/timeline) and [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/260146/timeline). Some questions show this while some don't. I also checked most of my questions on English Language and Usage, they also have "became hot network question". What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations! By posting a question which got quite a few upvotes soon after you created it, and/or an answer with a good score, it made it into the Hot Network Questions list, which you see in the sidebar of most Q&A pages through the Stack Exchange network (see the screenshot below). You can view it as some kind of advertisement for your question.

[image]

If you're interested, there's a lot of information about this feature on Meta Stack Exchange, for example in the following topics:

- [What is the Goal of "Hot Network Questions"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219922/295232)
- [What are the criteria for questions to be selected for Hot Network Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60756/295232)
- [Updating the Hot Network Questions List - now with a bit more network and a little less "hotness"!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060/295232)

Comment: Thanks Glorifindel! After posting this question, I went through all my questions on this community and English Language and Usage, most of my questions have "become hot network questions". :)